# Is it possible to install Android's .apk file?

Tags: android

Was just wondering it would be nice to have a convenient way of installing android's .apk apps in Ubuntu somehow.

Somebody has a clue about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to run Android apps in Ubuntu (as far as I'm aware) is to install Android SDK, create a virtual Android device, use the SDK's tools to install the .apk file on that device and run the app inside the device.

[Android developer portal](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) has a lot of info on the subject.

Comment: OK seems you're assumption is right, there is no other way of installing them. Will accept it then.

Answer (score 5):

Android packages, **.apk** files, are a completely different packaging format than Ubuntu's packaging format, **.deb** files.

Besides the packaging differences, Android packages are compiled and customized for the Android operating system, toolchain, and architecture (**ARM**), which is different from most Ubuntu systems which are 32-bit or 64-bit **Intel** architecture.

Comment: Yes and no. APKs aren't debs, but that's kind of the point of the question. Most Android applications are in fact pure Java, but compiled to a non-standard bytecode format (Dalvik instead of the standard JVM) and against a different API. Even Ubuntu on ARM couldn't run Android apps, or Ubuntu on x86 run Android x86 apps, without a large emulation layer (which doesn't exist short of emulating the whole machine in Qemu).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the **apk** installer code from Android x86 and compile it for Ubuntu, because Android x86 is linux, it use the same boot loader and kernel.

If someone can install the **apk** loader, JAVA runtime an all things you need to run apps, would the **apk** installer app install **apk**'s on Ubuntu the same way as in Android?

I don't know, but someone can try out.

Answer (score 0):

Android, though comes under Apache license, uses its own unique **APIs & libraries** to develop its apps (**.apk files**).

Just to make Android apps to run on a Linux machine, what you can do is compile the DVM (Dalvik Virtual Machine) source code using **Git** repo in Ubuntu so as to merge the DVM into your Linux PC. That will set the environment for Android architecture (i.e. **Linux kernel + Android DVM**). But additionally, you would also need to install the Android core libraries as well to make the apps fully functionable.

This is the best way you can run Android apps conveniently on Ubuntu.

Comment: but that's a whole lot of work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Android apps available in Market and Play Store are designed for ARM architecture processor and thus, what you are trying to do will never work for almost every other app you try to install on computer.

By the way, you can find a site on Google by searching 'porting Android on x86'. This will give you Android 4.2 to Android Froyo ROMs for your PC standalone installation. I had tried them, and almost 99% of software either refused to installed or refused to run after installation done, anyhow.

So, the major difference is x86 versus ARM series. And until we are able to virtually provide ARM processor architecture to Android, we can't do any thing.

Answer (score -1):

its actually not possible to run the APK file on an Ubuntu PC as Ubuntu will not be able to read it. The best among many things is to install an Android virtual machine and run the APK.